# How to prove the emptiness of intersection of two context free languages is undecidable?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, reference-request, undecidability

Where can I find a proof that the emptiness problem for the intersection of two context free languages is undecidable? I searched on the internet but could not find anything helpful.

Do you maybe have a book or paper I should investigate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A popular reference is the article [*Undecidable Problems for Context-free Grammars*](https://liacs.leidenuniv.nl/~hoogeboomhj/second/codingcomputations.pdf) by [Hendrik Jan Hoogeboom](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/4287/hendrik-jan).

The following is a proof taken from [this note](http://kilby.stanford.edu/~rvg/154/handouts/ambi.html) by Rob van Glabbeek.

---

**Theorem**: It is undecidable whether or not the languages generated by two given context-free grammars have an empty intersection.

**Proof**: By a reduction of post correspondence problem (which is known to be undecidable) to the empty intersection problem.
Given a set $d_1,\cdots,d_n$ of dominos where, for $i=1,\cdots,n$, the top string of $d_i$ is $w_i$ and the bottom string of $d_i = x_i$. Consider the context-free grammars

$$W\to w_1Wd_1\mid w_2Wd_2\mid\cdots\mid w_nWd_n\mid w_1d_1\mid w_2d_2\mid\cdots\mid w_nd_n$$ 
and 
$$X\to x_1Xd_1\mid x_2Xd_2\mid\cdots\mid x_nXd_n\mid x_1d_1\mid x_2d_2\mid\cdots\mid x_nd_n.$$

Now notice that the given instance of PCS has a match exactly when the intersection of the languages generated by the resulting grammars above is nonempty.

Comment: Using this would give me the word as well as the indices of the dominos in reverse order right?

Comment: Let $s$ be generated by $W$, i.e., $s=w_{i_1}w_{i_2}\cdots w_{i_k}d_{i_k}\cdots d_{i_2}d_{i_1}$.  If it is also generated by $X$, then $s=x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_k}d_{i_k}\cdots d_{i_2}d_{i_1}$. Cancelling $d_{i_k}\cdots d_{i_2}d_{i_1}$, we get $w_{i_1}w_{i_2}\cdots w_{i_k}=x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_k}$. Treating $d_i$ as the domino $\dfrac{w_i}{x_i}$, we get $d_{i_1}d_{i_2}\cdots d_{i_k}=\dfrac{w_{i_1}}{x_{i_1}}\dfrac{w_{i_2}}{x_{i_2}}\cdots\dfrac{w_{i_n}}{x_{i_n}}$, where the top and bottom are the same string.

Comment: can we use the same proof to show that the non emptiness of intersection of two cfls is also non decidable?

Comment: @rsonx Checking the non-emptiness is the same as checking the emptiness. If the intersection is empty, then it is not non-empty. If it is not empty, then it is non-empty.