# Is the emptiness problem for PEGs decidable?

Tags: formal-grammars

The emptiness problem for Context Free Grammars is decidable. Does the same hold for Parsing Expression Grammars (PEGs)? That is, is it decidable given a PEG $G$ to find whether $L(G) = \emptyset$ or not.

My intuition says no, as PEGs are closed under intersection, allowing one to construct hard instances of intersection, but I haven't given the proof a lot more thought. The [classic reduction to the PCP](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/109516/22714) doesn't work I believe - at least simply replacing choice with ordered choice - as this changes what languages are accepted.

Comment: Regrettably, I am not familiar with these grammars, but isn't ordered choice forcing the parse rather than the language?

Comment: @Hendrik Jan Consider $S = a / aa$ where $/$ is the ordered choice operator. In this case $L(S) = \{a\}$. Unintuitively $aa$ is not accepted because first $a$ is attempted which succeeds, thus the second choice is never evaluated.

Comment: Thanks. So the operator is like "greedy". I misunderstood, and thought is was more like "backtrack" (the parse does not fully succeed, so we try the alternative).

Comment: @HendrikJan It is backtracking, but only locally. It will never backtrack back over a successful (partial) parse even if later down the line it causes a failure. A positive side-effect of this is that PEGs are parsable in linear time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I should have done my research better before asking. The original paper introducing PEGs ([*Parsing Expression Grammars:
A Recognition-Based Syntactic Foundation*](https://bford.info/pub/lang/peg.pdf) by Bryan Ford) actually contains a proof that emptiness is undecidable, indeed using the post correspondence problem.